# Uploading Image to Firebase Storage and Database

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I want to put the download URL of images into my Firebase Database. I can upload the Image into storage but I can't figure out how to get the URL into my database with the rest of the "post".

```
@IBOutlet weak var titleText: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var authorText: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var mainText: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var dateText: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!

var ref:FIRDatabaseReference?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


@IBAction func uploadImage(_ sender: Any) {


       let image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self
    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary

    image.allowsEditing = false

    self.present(image, animated: true)
    {
        //after its completed
    }
}


@objc(imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:) func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    {
        myImageView.image = image

    }
    else
    {
        //error
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("myImage.png")
    if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.myImageView.image!){
        storageRef.put(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion:
            {
                (metadata, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("error")
                    return
                }

   print(metadata)

   //how do I put the download URL in the metadata into my database

        }  
        )
    }

}

@IBAction func addPost(_ sender: Any) {

    if self.titleText.text != "" && self.authorText.text != "" && self.mainText.text != "" && self.dateText.text != ""
    {

        ref?.child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(["Title": titleText.text,"Article": mainText.text, "Author": authorText.text, "Date": dateText.text, "myImageURL": myImageURL])

        //the myImageURL part is where I get an error

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "post", sender: self)

    }
    else{

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: "Field left blank", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Organize your `upload` and `save` funcs like this:

```
func uploadMedia(completion: @escaping (_ url: String?) -> Void) { 
    let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("myImage.png")
    if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.myImageView.image!) {
        storageRef.put(uploadData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("error")
                completion(nil)
            } else {
                completion((metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString)!)) 
                // your uploaded photo url.
            }
       }
 }
```

Next just connect to `FIRDatabase` and save it to your node.

```
 @IBAction func addPost(_ sender: Any) {
     if self.titleText.text   != "" && self.authorText.text != "" 
        && self.mainText.text != "" && self.dateText.text   != "" {
     
     uploadMedia() { url in 
          guard let url = url else { return }
          ref?.child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue([
                                "Title"      : titleText.text,
                                "Article"    : mainText.text, 
                                "Author"     : authorText.text, 
                                "Date"       : dateText.text, 
                                "myImageURL" : url
                                ])
     }
 }
```

You can also look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43930248/5878081) about uploading data and saving URL's to database

Comment: So how do I put it in my database?  ref?.child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(["Title": titleText.text,"Article": mainText.text, "Author": authorText.text, "Date": dateText.text ])

Answer (score 10):

For Updated Firebase Version And Swift 4.2 Code :

```
 func uploadMedia(completion: @escaping (_ url: String?) -> Void) {

    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("\(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "").png")
    if let uploadData = self.imgUploadView.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) {
        storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("error")
                completion(nil)
            } else {

                storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in

                    print(url?.absoluteString)
                    completion(url?.absoluteString)
                })

              //  completion((metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString)!))
                // your uploaded photo url.


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**100% working tested just one add function**

```
 //MARK: - Upload image
func uploadImage(_ image: UIImage){
 
    let imageName:String = String("\(CurrentTimeStampInSecond).png")
    
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profilePic").child(imageName)
    let compressImage = HelperFunction.helper.resizeImage(image: image)
    if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(compressImage){
        storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil
            , completion: { (metadata, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("error")
                     self.stopAnimating()
                    showAlertWithTitleWithMessage(message: "Please try again later")
                    return
                }else{
                    self.stopAnimating()
                }
                
                let strPic:String = (metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString)!
                               
                print(metadata)
                //self.imagePath = (metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString)!
                //self.sendMessageOnServer()
                print("\n\n\n\n\n\n ===download url : \(strPic)")
                   
        })
        
    }
}
```

Comment: 'StorageMetadata' has no member 'downloadURL' giving me this error

Answer (score 0):

It might be too late, but I have found an easier way by using a [Utility Class to Upload Images & Files to Firebase Storage](https://handyopinion.com/utility-class-to-upload-images-videos-files-to-firebase-storage-in-swift-ios/.). You can upload images and files with a single method call, using the above utility class. like

```
if let data = image.pngData() { // convert your UIImage into Data object using png representation
      FirebaseStorageManager().uploadImageData(data: data, serverFileName: "your_server_file_name.png") { (isSuccess, url) in
             print("uploadImageData: \(isSuccess), \(url)")
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Use UIImagePNGRepresentation in swift 4.2 like this,

 if let uploadData = profileImageView.image?.pngData() {
                    storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
                        if error != nil {

                        }
                    }
                }
```