# How do I add a printed item to Firebase Database?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to take a printed item and inserting it into my Firebase Database along with the rest of outlets. Thanks!

```
@objc(imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:) func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        myImageView.image = image  
    } else {
        //error
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("myImage.png")
    if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.myImageView.image!) {
        storageRef.put(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion:
        {
                (metadata, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("error")
                    return
                } else {
                    print((metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString)!)
                   //i want to take the line above and insert it into the database
                }
        })
     }           
}

@IBAction func addPost(_ sender: Any) {

    if self.titleText.text != "" && self.authorText.text != "" && self.mainText.text != "" && self.dateText.text != "" {
        ref?.child("Posts").childByAutoId()
                           .setValue(["Title": titleText.text,
                                      "Article": mainText.text,
                                      "Author": authorText.text,
                                      "Date": dateText.text ])

        //insert the download URL above 
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "kost", sender: self)    
    }
}
```

Comment: Did my answer help, maybe some further explanation of your question would be helpful

Comment: Answered for your question here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44061967/5878081

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading Image to Firebase Storage and Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44060518/uploading-image-to-firebase-storage-and-database)

Comment: Can you explain specifically what isn't working? There may be some coding errors; *storageRef.put(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion:* should probably be *storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in*.  See the [Firebase Upload Files Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what your problem is now. You are tackling uploading images to firebase in totally the wrong manner. In the event `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` you should not be doing anything with firebase. You should only be setting your UIImageViews image to store the value of the data given from the image picker.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    if let editedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage{
        myImageView.image = editedImage
    }else{
        print("Something went wrong")
    }
}
```

Then in your IBAction, you should upload everything to firebase. Here is a simple function that will upload your image to the database it:

```
func uploadImage(){
    if let fileData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImageView.image!, 0.8){
    let storageRef = storage.reference().child("images").child("testImage.jpg")
        storageRef.put(fileData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "error")
                return
            }
            let downloadURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
            // Write the download URL to your Database
            self.ref?.child("images").setValue(downloadURL)
        })
    }else{
        print("error")
    }
}
```

Comment: This statement *it is difficult to set variables inside a firebase closure* is totally inaccurate. Class vars can be easily set within a closure; self.var_name or self.myArray.append(snapshot) works every time.